# Appending a string on the specific place in txt file - Java

Tags: java, string, loops, file, txt

I'am trying to append string(link) to the txt file on the specific place(In line where is "Link:"), to get line in file like "Link: www.link.something". I am using next code but my logic doesn't work.

```
if(file.getName().equals(filename+".txt")) {
   link = line;
   BufferedReader br;
   BufferedWriter bw;
   boolean no=false;
   String lineE;
   String data="Link:";
   String lessonPath=link;
                                                
                                                
   br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    
    
   while((lineE =br.readLine()) !=null){
      if(!no){
         data=line;
         no=true;
      }else{
         data = data+"\n"+lineE;
      }   
   }
   bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
   bw.write(data+"\n"+lessonPath);
   System.out.println(data+lessonPath);
   bw.flush();
   bw.close();  
   br.close(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the text file then you could use [StringSubstitutor](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/StringSubstitutor.html) to replace the template.

Comment: I tried to do this by concatenating an already existing line of a text file with string of the link

Comment: Some other solution?